# Grab useful data between strings using python from a file

Tags: python

I have the following Raw data from a HTML source code file

```
{$deletedFields:[courses,projects,description,degreeName,recommendations,honors,entityLocale,activities,grade,fieldOfStudyUrn,testScores,degreeUrn],entityUrn:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,75863717),school:urn:li:fs_miniSchool:11709,timePeriod:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,75863717),timePeriod,schoolName:Charles University in Prague,fieldOfStudy:Economics, Politics,schoolUrn:urn:li:fs_miniSchool:11709,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.Education},
{$deletedFields:[courses,projects,description,recommendations,honors,entityLocale,activities,grade,fieldOfStudyUrn,testScores,degreeUrn],entityUrn:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,26812055),school:urn:li:fs_miniSchool:17888,timePeriod:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,26812055),timePeriod,degreeName:BA,schoolName:Occidental College,fieldOfStudy:Economics,schoolUrn:urn:li:fs_miniSchool:17888,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.Education},
{$deletedFields:[],profileId:ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,elements:[urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,26812055),urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,75863717)],paging:urn:li:fs_profileView:ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,educationView,paging,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.EducationView,$id:urn:li:fs_profileView:ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,educationView},
{$deletedFields:[],start:501,end:1000,$type:com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.EmployeeCountRange,$id:urn:li:fs_position:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,323432440),company,employeeCountRange}



{$deletedFields:[month,day],year:2007,$type:com.linkedin.common.Date,$id:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,75863717),timePeriod,startDate},
{$deletedFields:[month,day],year:2004,$type:com.linkedin.common.Date,$id:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,26812055),timePeriod,startDate},
{$deletedFields:[month,day],year:2008,$type:com.linkedin.common.Date,$id:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,26812055),timePeriod,endDate},
{$deletedFields:[month,day],year:2007,$type:com.linkedin.common.Date,$id:urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAAAIUJvgBC7QTHSmLEjgtomzxvwceeM71E1c,75863717),timePeriod,endDate},
```

What i need is extract some data out of it using.

```
schoolname = re.findall(r',schoolname:(.*?),' , page_html)
fieldofstudy = skills = re.findall(r'fieldOfStudy:(.*?),s' , page_html)
degreename = re.findall(r'degreeName:(.*?),' , page_html)
```

## Needed Output

schoolName:Charles University in Prague

fieldOfStudy:Economics, Politics

Start : Year 2007

End : 2007

schoolName:Occidental College

fieldOfStudy:Economics

degreeName:BA

start : 2004

End : 2008

Comment: you need to edit your question. This is not a python dicts and not a way to ask a question.

Comment: Its HTML source I want to extract information out of it.

Comment: Your first part isn't a python code (not a dict, not a str or anything else). Please provide a well formated data in your question.

Comment: As i mentioned the data is in garbage form so i need to extract information from that.
How can you even format this type of data?

Comment: is it in a `dict` or `str` format?

Comment: its in string format.
i just used 
    `file = open(r"live.txt")`
    `page_html = file.read()`
    `file.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: What i need is extract some data out of it using

Define a Data Container `class School`:

```
class School(object):
    def __init__(self, raw_data):
        key = None
        year = '?'
        for kv in raw_data:
            i = kv.find(':')
            if i >= 0:
                key = kv[0:i]
                value = kv[i + 1:]
                if key in ['schoolName', 'fieldOfStudy', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'degreeName']:
                    object.__setattr__(self, key, value)

                if key in ['year']:
                    year = value
            else:
                if key in ['entityUrn', '$id']:
                    if kv[:-1].isdigit():
                        self.entity = kv[:-1]
                elif key in ['fieldOfStudy']:
                    self.fieldOfStudy += ', '+kv
                elif kv in ['startDate', 'endDate']:
                    object.__setattr__(self, kv, year)
                key = ''

            if not hasattr(self, 'degreeName'):
                self.degreeName = 'unknown'

    def __repr__(self):
        return "entity:\t\t{s.entity:>28}\n" \
               "schoolName:\t{s.schoolName:>28}\n" \
               "fieldOfStudy:{s.fieldOfStudy:>27}\n" \
               "degreeName:\t{s.degreeName:>28}\n" \
               "startDate:\t{s.startDate:>28}\n" \
               "endDate:\t{s.endDate:>28}\n".format(s=self)
```

Read the file line by line:

```
with open('<path to file>') as fh:
    degreeUrn = {}
    for line in fh:
        match = re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\:\[(.*?)\],(.*)\}', line)
        m2 = match[0][2].split(',')
        school = School(m2)
        if hasattr(school, 'entity'):
            if hasattr(school, 'startDate'):
                degreeUrn[school.entity].startDate = school.startDate
                del school
            elif hasattr(school, 'endDate'):
                degreeUrn[school.entity].endDate = school.endDate
                del school
            elif hasattr(school, 'schoolName'):
                degreeUrn[school.entity] = school
        else:
            del school

for entity in degreeUrn:
    print(degreeUrn[entity])
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> entity:                         75863717
> schoolName: Charles University in Prague
> fieldOfStudy:       Economics,  Politics
> degreeName:                      unknown
> startDate:                          2007
> endDate:                            2007
>
> entity:                         26812055
> schoolName:           Occidental College
> fieldOfStudy:                  Economics
> degreeName:                           BA
> startDate:                          2004
> endDate:                            2008
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***